# Angular POST using x-www-formurl-encoded not working

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, post

This is the method I am using to post

```js
let body2 =`client_id=C123&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://redirecturl.com&code=abc-123`

let header = new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "client_id": "C123"
})
let options = { headers: header }

this.http.post<any>(http://posturl.com, body2, options)
```

The response is `Invalid Client`

But when I make the same call using ajax I am getting the desired response

```js
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://posturl.com',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                "client_id": "C123",
                "grant_type": "authorization_code",
                "redirect_uri": "http://redirecturl.com",
                "code": "abc-123"
            },
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "client_id": "C123"
            },
            done: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
```

Now I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: are you sure you need to send let body2 =`client_id=C123&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://redirecturl.com&code=abc-123` ? ,  because you are sending playing object in ajax

Comment: I have to send data as urlencoded. This is what I found on how to send it.

Comment: It there a way I can send same data in angular what I am sending in ajax?

Comment: yes sure just send it same way as you are sending in ajax , this.http.post("/api/url", { client_id:"c123',grant_type.... }, options)

Comment: I have tried that . The error I am getting is Invalid request

Comment: Also the form data in ajax method is `client_id: C123 grant_type: autho.....` and the form data from what you suggested is {"client_id":"C123", "grant_type","autho....}

Comment: Why are you sending form data content type isn't it just json ?

Comment: No. It's x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: I have mentioned it in the question

Comment: try the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
let body2 = {
            client_id: "C123",
            grant_type: "authorization_code",
            redirect_uri: "http://redirecturl.com",
            code: "abc-123"
        }
var formData = new FormData();

for ( var key in body2) {
    formData.append(key, item[key]);
}
this.http.post("http://posturl.com", formData).subscribe();
```